# citation for encoding binary inputs to neural net as -1 and 1

Tags: neural-networks, references, binary-data

I've seen the recommendation that binary inputs to a neural network should be encoded as -1 and 1 rather than 0 and 1 in a few places on the internet ([here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part2/) and [here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/07/01/neural-network-data-normalization-and-encoding.aspx)).

Does anyone know of a published peer reviewed citation that supports (or opposes) this recommendation?

Comment: The curious thing about neural networks is that about 20% of the knowledge about how NNs work is "folk knowledge" that is stored and  disseminated in non-traditional media like Reddit threads, the SAS NN FAQ and Github issue trackers.